# Compilation error in specifying template arguments in boost::unordered_map

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I was writing wrapper methods for Boost unordered map container. In boost Unordered Map there is a method begin(),
which returns an iterator to the first element. In my wrapper i trying to write a templatized wrapper. For example

```
template< class Tkey, class Tvalue>
class CMyUnorderedMap
{
       boost::Unordered_map<TKey,  TValue> m_myMap;
    public:
       boost::unordered_map<TKey,  TValue>::iterator Begin();

};

template< class Tkey, class Tvalue> 
boost::unordered_map<TKey,  TValue>::iterator CMyUnorderedMap< TKey,  TValue >::Begin()
{
    return   m_myMap.begin()
}
```

While compiling the above code(with template argument) i am getting compilation error in VS 2010 as below.

warningc4346: boost::unordered::unordered_map< TKey,  TValue>::iterator : dependent name is not a type.

error C3860 template argument list following class template name must list paramaters in the order used in tempate paramater list

But if i compile the code with out template argument the code complies.
for example if a specify like below it works

```
boost::unordered_map< std::string,  std::string>::iterator Begin();
```

Will any one help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It worked after i changed the code as below

```
class CMyUnorderedMap
{

   boost::Unordered_map<TKey,  TValue> m_myMap;
public:
 typename boost::unordered_map<TKey,  TValue>::iterator Begin();

};

template< class Tkey, class Tvalue>
```

Added the key word **typename** in decleration and defenition of the function

```
typename boost::unordered_map<TKey,  TValue>::iterator CMyUnorderedMap< TKey,  TValue >::Begin()

{

    return   m_myMap.begin()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When defining a member function of the class template outside the body of the class template, you need to specify the template details.

For your case, you need to use:

```
template< class Tkey, class Tvalue> // Missing from your code.
boost::unordered_map<TKey,  TValue>::iterator CMyUnorderedMap< TKey,  TValue >::Begin()
{
    return   m_myMap.begin()
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu i specified class template outside the body of the class template, still there is compilation error

Comment: @Ushus, please lease post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the compiler error message(s). It's not productive to talk via comments.